# Batch MYSQL Inserts with parent relations in transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Considering two tables (I've simplified it a bit, in reality there are more related tables and more columns):

```
TABLE 'visit'
-------------
- id (auto increment)
- visit_country
- visit_browser

TABLE 'pageview'
----------------
- id
- visit_id (relates to visit.id)
- page_url
```

Every day, I want to insert a PHP array with around 100.000 visits and 400.000 hits into these tables. The way to speed this process up is by

- adding multiple inserts into one query
- and wrapping up the entire bunch of queries into a transaction.

However, my problem is that in order to insert the pageview, the Last Insert ID of the parent visit is required. In a transaction where let's say a 1000 visits are inserted using one query, I can no longer use PDO's lastInsertId() method.

Ideally I keep everything into one transaction. A less ideal solution would be to insert all visits and add a reference column, then execute, check which ID each visit got and then use a new transaction to insert the hits. But that is far from ideal.

What would be the way to approach this? How do ORM's like Doctrine solve this problem (I need to rely on raw SQL through PDO here)?

Comment: This is too broad a question. Use a stored procedure on the database side to do the insert?

Comment: what is the question here? what's wrong with wrapping up the entire bunch of queries into a transaction? Inserting 100.000 records is like 2-3 seconds on the average hardware. Did you actually try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do make the query something like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `visit` (`id`, `visit_country`, `visit_browser`) 
VALUES (NULL, :visit_country, :visit_browser);
INSERT INTO `pageview` (`visit_id`, `page_url`) 
VALUES (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), :page_url)";
```

than prepare, bindparam & execute

Comment: Oh that's perfect! Trying it out now, will accept your answer asap if that works.

Comment: @dirk this code is no different from using  PDO's lastInsertId() method so how it can solve any real world problem that lastInsertId() doesnt?

Comment: True, I am unfamiliar with transactions, and I thought I still needed to batch the inserts together into one query with transactions but that doesn't seem to be necessary in order to get the speed benefits. Just tested locally inserting 120K rows, which takes 6 minutes without transactions and 18 seconds with the exact same individual queries but wrapped in a transaction. That is good enough for me. Apologies if I didn't ask for the right thing here, but the answer provided by Ronak actually helped me out.